# compounding L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits

This is might be a simple question, but I havent been able to find the answer.

I'm trying to find the limit of A(x)/x, where A(x) goes to infinity as x does. Applying L'Hôpital's rule the answer is the limit of A'(x). Now it turns out that A'(x) itself is a fraction A'(x)=B(x)/C(X) which everything going to infinity. Can I know apply L'Hôpital's rule again to B(x)/C(X), and will that equal the original limit of A(x)/x given that the limit exists?

Comment: You can continue using  L'Hôpital's rule (not to say you must).

Comment: Why would you think that you cannot still apply L'H? As long as the hypothesis are satisfied then the rule applies, no matter the source of the limit. In many cases iterating L'H is inefficient, amounting to canceling a common factor of $\,x^k\,$ from Taylor series expansions of the numerator and denominator.